# Reduce server TTFB

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have an application which uploads and reads files from another VPS (i.e. file server, Ubuntu 18.04). These servers are in the same network. The application (.NET core) uses SFTP protocol (SSH.net) for files reading/writing.

For a 5 Mb file it takes 3 seconds to load a file, more than 2 seconds of which is the TTFB (80% of total time).

Is there a way to reduce the TTFB and accelerate file transfer/load?

Comment: Please tell us more what you have to use this special usage case, and why it must be sftp instead of a other protocol like nfs or similar with less overhead?

Comment: What is the time to upload or download a similar sized file with an sftp client external to your application? In other words, is it ssh to the remote that is slow to the first byte, or your application?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an ssh connection takes quite a bit of time. Two seconds isn't unreasonable. If you mean to transfer multiple files during a session, whatever that means for your application, you should leave the connection open between file transfers and reuse it to avoid this delay. Our sister site Stack Overflow can help you if you get stuck with fixing your application.